# python list iteration over a sequence of numbers with "breaking points"

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, append

I have a list of numbers :

list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I would like through iteration to take all the numbers of every breaking point. Let's say
from 3 to 1 i want to keep 3, from 4 to 1 i want to keep 4 and keep also the last number of the list
and append it to a new list. I would like to have an output:

new_list = [3,4,5,8]

Comment: What do you mean by breaking point?

Comment: i would like to run through this list and take all these numbers at the points where the next one is smaller than the previous one. For example new_list = [3,4,5,8]

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please post the code and mention the issue you are facing.

Comment: i have a list of time with starting and ending time steps and i want to add the duration of every step. From the above list i want an outtput duration = 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
new_list = []

last_index = len(list)-1

#Iterate till last but one-element
for i in range(last_index):
    #If the number is greater than the next number, append it
    if list[i] > list[i+1]:
        new_list.append(list[i])

#The last element will come in the list even if it is smaller than its previous number
new_list.append(list[last_index])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution making use of itertool.pairwise (by the way, it's a bad idea to name your list `list`, since it overwrites Python's built-in class):

```
from itertools import pairwise

my_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

break_points = [a for (a, b) in pairwise(my_list) if a > b]
break_points += my_list[-1:]
```

Comment: `break_points += my_list[-1:]` would be safer (doesn't crash if the list is empty).

Comment: Good call, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To record the end of each increasing sequence, you can iterate through the list while keeping track of the last number and comparing it to the current one. Here's an example of a simple loop to accomplish this

```py
list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
newList = []
lastNum = 0
for i, num in enumerate(list):
    if i > 0 and num < lastNum:
        newList.append(lastNum)
    lastNum = num
newList.append(list[len(list)-1])
print(newList)
```

You could also use a look-ahead strategy and simplify the logic

```py
list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
newList = []
for i, num in enumerate(list):
    if i == len(list)-1 or num > list[i+1]:
        newList.append(num)
    lastNum = num
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you determine your so-called 'breakpoints' can be made clearer (in the code) if you write a function (generator in this case) that calculates where the breakpoints occur.

Something like this:

```
from itertools import pairwise

_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def breakpoints(_lst):
    for a, b in pairwise(_lst):
        if a > b:
            yield a
    yield _lst[-1]

result = list(breakpoints(_list))

print(result)
```